# MomentJS gets different UNIX timestamps on different platforms

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have encountered interesting problem:

I have an timestamp with value `1500400800`

I want to get staart of day and end of day of this timestamp. By using `moment.js` I have written this code:

```
let timestamp = 1500400800;
let momentDate = moment.unix(timestamp);

let start = momentDate.startOf('day').unix();
let end = momentDate.endOf('day').unix();
console.log(timestamp + " "  + start + " " + end);
```

My own PC returns for `1500400800` these values:

```
1500400800 1500400800 1500487199
```

But virutal machine in my hosting returns this:

```
1500400800 1500336000 1500422399
```

They are different. There are **six hours difference** between two platforms.

How to make virtual hosting machine get timestamps just like my local PC gets?

Comment: No idea how momentjs works, but you most likely need to set the timezone. More on that here: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment assumes time relative to the time of the local system. Your virtual server either has an incorrect clock or is located in another timezone. You can either work exclusively in UTC by telling moment to convert to UTC, or you might look into [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) which is an extension of moment built specifically for working in multiple timezones.